# How can I test a web service which receives a file as a parameter

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-boot

I am creating a `Spring REST` web service for someone who got a client which will use my web service.

Up until now, the web service received only some strings as paramters so I did not have a problem simply using a web browser to check the web service by entering a URL which addressed the web service using a `GET` request which I simply typed manually. It was something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/service?param1="hi"&param2="hi"
```

Now param2 is supposed to receive a file. This is defined in the web service like this:

```
@RequestParam(value="param2", required=true) MultipartFile param2
```

How can I now test the web service? How is it possible to send a file with no client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a REST client plugin like Postman for Chrome. It supports files as parameters. Note, that you can't send files in GET requests, only in POST.

Comment: Is it possible if you could explain how can I test the web service with it? I installed Postman and there I found an option to install a REST client which I did, but there I'm not sure in the POST tab, what is the difference between the headers and payload. Where do I enter the parameters names and values? and how do I pass a file?

Comment: OK I believe I got how to enter the parameters values after changing the content type to x-www-form-urlencoded.  but I am still not sure how can I pass a file.

Comment: You have to choose form-data, then you can pass a file

Comment: I went to the form tab but I can only write keys and values manually. I got a seperate tab for files but I can't give it a key like the parameters in the form tab

Comment: OK it seems like I installed an "Advanced REST client" through POSTMAN which is something different than POSTMAN itself. After using POSTMAN it was all good.